# Finding Multiple modes in an Array C programming

Tags: c

I have this homework assignment where the user would enter 10 numbers and would find the mode of those 10 numbers. I got one mode working, my question is I dont know how to start finding multiple modes in the array. EX. 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 The mode of the array is 1,2

Here's the code for the mode

```
void displayMode(int numArray[])
{

    int countArray[MAX];
    int modeCount = 0;
    int modeNumber;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i=0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        countArray[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            if (numArray[i] == numArray[j])
                countArray[i]++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (countArray[i] > modeCount)
        {
            modeCount = countArray[i];
            modeNumber = numArray[i];
        }   
    }


    if (modeCount > 1)
        printf("\nThe mode of the array is: %d",modeNumber);
    else
        printf("\nThe mode of the array is: None");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a container with size. This is easily achievable with `std::vector` in C++, but anyway, this is a rough (not memory efficient) implementation in C.

Use modeNumbers instead of one, and create a variable for size:

```
int modeNumbers[MAX];
size_t modeSize = 0;
```

Then, append with size:

```
if (countArray[i] > modeCount)
{
    modeCount = countArray[i];
    modeNumbers[0] = numArray[i];
    modeSize = 1;
} else if (countArray[i] == modeCount) {
    modeNumbers[modeSize++] = numArray[i];
}
```

Finally, use a for loop to output it:

```
if (modeCount > 1) {
    printf("\nThe mode of the array is: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < modeSize; ++i) { printf("%s%d", i == 0?"":", ", modeNumbers[i]; }
} else {
    printf("\nThe mode of the array is: None");
}
```

Comment: hey,thanks for the help it worked but i wanted to ask another question how would i output just 1 number like the output is 1,1,2,2 if the mode was 1 and 2, i wanted it to be like 1,2 as the output